# Add text after span text not within the span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Check this screenshot:

[image]

I am using this code to add span of emoji in DIV.

```
$('body').on('click', '.selectable-icons', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'span') {
        document.querySelector('[contenteditable]').appendChild(e.target.cloneNode(true));
        $('[contenteditable]').append(" ");
        var current_text = $('[contenteditable]').html();
        alert(current_text);
        $('.publisher_div').html(current_text);
    }
```

But space is not appending after `span` tag, so that I can write next text after `span` tag.

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: Have you tried to use `&nbsp;` ?

Comment: @hallleron: Stack Snippets, not fiddles.

Answer (score 3):

`$('[contenteditable]').append(" ");` will append a space to the elements with a `contenteditable` attribute (the `span`, in your case). If you want to add the space **after**, use http://api.jquery.com/after/:

```
$('[contenteditable]').after(" ");
```

Live Example:

```js
var container = $("#container");
console.log("Before:");
container.contents().each(function(index) {
    console.log(index, this.nodeType, this.nodeType === 3 ? '"' + this.nodeValue + '"' : this.tagName);
});
$('[contenteditable]').after(" ");
console.log("After:");
container.contents().each(function(index) {
    console.log(index, this.nodeType, this.nodeType === 3 ? '"' + this.nodeValue + '"' : this.tagName);
});
```

```html
<div id="container"><span contenteditable>This is the span</span></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $('.publisher_div').append("hi");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$('[contenteditable]').append("&nbsp;");
```

Comment: *"add text after span text… NOt within the span tag"* `append` adds *within*.